# TPM key store unlock in embedded system

Tags: tpm

When using a TPM on a PC, you typically unlock the key store by means of a password that the user can enter. However, in an embedded system there typically is no user present that can enter a password. Are there any alternatives for how you can unlock the TPM key store? For instance, is there a way to specify that if measure boot PCRs have a certain value, the key store is unlocked? The logic would be that if the system is running the expected software the key store can be opened. Or are there other ways for how to unlock the key store when no user is present to enter a password?

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical necessity for using a password.

You can `seal` the key data. The *sealing* operation allows you to control which PCRs shall be checked and the value they should have at the time someone tries to *unseal* the data.

Comment: but as a side note, sealing, after the kernel started and the modules are loaded -- and the operating system takes over to start its services -- it gets really hard to determine pcr values you can use for sealing. If you want to do that, you need a strict sequential boot sequence, or else you won't find a suitable and consitent pcr value over multiple restarts.

Comment: @evildead this usually does not apply to classic embedded systems. In most cases you have full control over PCRs.

Comment: @Scolytus.I'm no expert in embedded systems, or lets say that depends on the definition. Could you be a little more detailed how the system startup is controlled in the "classic" systems you mean to maintain consistent PCRs for post boot measurements in PCR 10 like e.g. IMA does? Or is the system startup there strictly sequentially? Because I see no strong argument to seal with a PCR not reflecting the current system state and am really interested in solutions for that.

Comment: @evildead As always, the answer is "it depends". If you want to attest a system after one year of runtime with publicly available services, I'd say there's no general solution for that yet. If you have a specific problem in mind, feel free to post a question.

Comment: Attesting a system does not rely on a premature well-known PCR value after boot or any time later, as it just reflects the current system state and can be calculated by consulting the IMA-list. I'm talking specifically about unsealing. I totally get your point that there exists specifically crafted embedded systems on which you can fully control the boot process accordingly, but you said "in most cases" it is possible. So I just wanted to have an example for that, as I did not find any system fulfilling this requirement out of the box.

Comment: @evildead How is this related to this Q/A?

Comment: It's related because you provide an academic solution for a real problem. If you knew a system supporting consistent states after booting, you would have just named it.

Comment: @evildead That's not an academic solution, that's how it's done in a dozen of production systems. Even my laptop has a deterministic, consistent, reproducable set of PCRs. What exactly is your point? OP asked how you unlock a key if a system booted in the right configuration. The answer is, seal the key to the PCR set representing that state. Period. That's how it's done. If you have a question on how to achieve that consistent state, feel free to post your own question describing your problem at hand and stop wasting my time. Obviously we are not talking about the same stuff here. EOD

Comment: I don't force you to reply to me and we are talking about the same stuff. OC PCR 1-7 are consistent, but what is the point to seal a key to one of these PCRs if your system is infected by malicious software or a malicious kernel module which is, in fact, not part of any measurement in PCR 1-7. If you define "booted in the right configuration" without regards to kernel modules and executed software, then you are right. If this is how it's done in a dozen of production systems, then they do it wrong.

Comment: You are talking kernel, PCR 1-7 and so on. So you most likely are talking about a PC platform with a static root of trust for measurement as defined in PC platform spec. That's *one* possible architecture. One I'd never advise to use. It's all about architecture. A TPM and its features are just building blocks.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about PC platform and I'm glad you don't advise to use that regarding sealing. As I said I have very limited experience with classic embedded devices. If there exists other architectures where it makes sense, then I'm fine with it. A point in the right direction would have been nice though. :)